# Vagrant 1.8.4, cant run provisioner shell from a file

Tags: shell, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I had to downgrade my vagrant version do to conflicts with chef. Now I am using Vagrant 1.8.4, but I have encountered a problem with the provisioner function.  This function should use the `bootstrap.sh` file that is present in the same directory as my vagrant file to bootstrap the instance I am creating.  Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

    #gives the instances 1 extra network eth interfaces
    config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"

    #creates instances, defines linux image, hostname and a script to run on creation
    config.vm.define "web1" do |web1|
        web1.vm.box = "trusty64"
        web1.vm.hostname = "web1"
        #this will run the script bootstrap.sh that is in the same directory as the Vagrantfile
        config.vm.provision :shell, path "bootstrap.sh"
    end
end
```

When running `vagrant up` I get the following error:

```
There is a syntax error in the following Vagrantfile. The syntax error
message is reproduced below for convenience:

/path/to/my/dir/Vagrantfile:14: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
        config.vm.provision :shell, path "bootstrap.sh"
                                          ^
```

What is the correct syntax for using a provisioner file in Vagrant 1.8.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 ways to write it in ruby

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap.sh"
```

or you could write

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"
```